# Format a time with timezone to local time in PHP

Tags: php, datetime-format

How can a change times that are provided with a timezone (eg. `14:00:00+02:00`) to a local time (the result would be `16:00:00`) when the dates are not provided.
I've tried it with the `DateTime` class. But since I'm only handling times, not dates, it doesn't always provide the correct results:

```
$time = '14:00:00+02:00';
$datetime = new DateTime($date);
$result = $datetime->format("H:i:s");
```

Comment: $datetime = new DateTime($date); should be $datetime = new DateTime($time); . Right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use setTimezone() function

```
$time = '14:00:00+02:00';
$datetime = new DateTime($time);
$result = $datetime->format("H:i:s");
echo $result;
echo '<br>';
$datetime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Your_local_timezone')); // ex: UTC (+00h00) or Europe/Moscow (+4h00)
$result = $datetime->format("H:i:s");
echo $result;
```

Comment: I've tried that but it only works if the suffix is is+01:00 '                 `$date = '14:00:00+01:00';
 $timezone;
    $datetime = new DateTime($date);
    $target_timezone = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Brussels');
    $datetime->setTimezone($target_timezone);
    $result = $datetime->format("H:i:s");
 echo $result;` gives 15:00:00 but with the +02:00 it gives 14:00:00

Comment: You can use for exemple 'Europe/Moscow' time zone (+04:00): $datetime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Moscow'));

Answer (score 0):

Use DateTime's [`setTimezone`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php) method. It will automatically change the time to match the timezone.

```
$date = new DateTo,e("2017-02-02 10:00:00", new DateTimeZone("+0200"));
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone("-0200"));
var_dump($date->format("H:i:s"));
```

Will output the following:

```
string '06:00:00' (length=8)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$utc = new DateTimeZone("UTC");
$zone = new DateTimeZone("YOUR_TIME_ZONE");
$date = new DateTime("14:00:00+02:00", $utc);
$date->setTimezone($zone);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should specific your time zone, and tell `DateTime` to use Time zones
for example:

```
$time = '14:00:00+02:00';
$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s+T', $time);
$datetime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Warsaw'));
$result = $datetime->format("H:i:s");

echo($result);
```

Use `+T` in format pattern to say php thats date contain a Time zone, in next step u should set your timezone using `setTimezone`. For example i set `'Europe/Warsaw'` but nothing happen coz +02:00 is `CEST` thats equal to `'Europe/Warsaw'`

Other way is changing `+02:00` to naming time zone here is a example:

```
$time = '14:00:00 (UTC)';
$datetime = new DateTime($time);

$datetime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Warsaw'));
$result = $datetime->format("H:i:s");

echo($result);
```